# How to stop a playlist of a game when the game state is pause and play again when the game finish the pause state? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop, playback, playlist, pause

I created a game that when is running sounds a playlist and when the player pause the game sounds a music ambient theme and the playlist stop but I don't know how to start over the playlist when the player finnish the pause state.
This is the Object for the Game State:

```
...
const GAMESTATE = {
    PAUSED: 0,
    RUNNING: 1,
    MENU: 2,
    GAMEOVER: 3,
    NEWLEVEL: 4
  };
...
```

Those are the songs on the playlist:

```
...
    constructor() {
        this.gameState = GAMESTATE.MENU;
        this.init = document.getElementById('init');
        this.gameState = GAMESTATE.MENU;
        this.pink = document.getElementById('pink');
        this.epic = document.getElementById('epic');
        this.rock = document.getElementById('rock');
        this.jungla = document.getElementById('jungla');
        this.luna = document.getElementById('luna');
        this.shot = document.getElementById('shot');
        this.piano = document.getElementById('piano');
        this.hight = document.getElementById('hight');
        this.bad = document.getElementById('bad');
        this.playList = [this.init, this.pink, this.epic, 
        this.rock, this.jungla, this.luna, this.shot, this.piano, 
        this.hight];
    }
...
```

Notice that the initial state of the game is the Menu state.
I made a function to randomize the playlist:

```
...
    getRandom() {
        return Math.floor(Math.random()*this.playList.length);
        }
...
```

Then I put at the beginning of each level that when a song is finished, another one starts at random, having a fixed song as a starting point. Like this:

```
...
    start() {
    if(this.gameState !== GAMESTATE.MENU && this.gameState !== 
    GAMESTATE.NEWLEVEL) return;
    this.gameState = GAMESTATE.RUNNING;
    for(i ; i < this.playList.length; i++) {
                this.playList[i].addEventListener('ended', () => {
                    this.playList[this.getRandom()].play();
                })
        }
    this.playList[0].play();
    }
...
```

I stop the playlist liske this:

```
...
    if(this.gameState === GAMESTATE.PAUSED) {
            this.bad.play();
            for(i = 0; i < this.playList.length; i++) {
                if(this.playList[i].play()) {
                    this.playList[i].pause();
                } 
    }
...
```

And I try to restart the playlist with:

```
...
   if(this.gameState === GAMESTATE.RUNNING) {
            this.bad.pause();
            for(i = 0; i < this.playList.length; i++) {
            if(this.playList[i].pause()) {
                    this.playList[i].play();
            }
    }
...
```

But this last step fails, what do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

#### Pausing

The `if` statement in your stop playlist function is **calling** the `play()` function.  What you want to be doing is **checking** the element to see if it is playing or not.  You can do that with the [`paused`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/paused) property of the `HTMLMediaElement`.

To stop all sounds: (your loops are not *wrong* but personally I find `forEach` to be a lot more readable.)

```
this.playList.forEach( el => { 
  if ( ! el.paused ) {
    el.pause();
  }
});
```

You could also just call `pause()` on all of them. The [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/pause) state

> if the media is already in a paused state this method will have no effect.

```
this.playList.forEach( el => el.pause() );
```

---

#### Resuming

In order to resume the playlist from where you left off you need to know which track you were last playing.  I'm not sure if you can figure that out by examining properties of the element, but you can definitely store that information in your class.

In your constructor, you can add an event listener to each element in the playlist.  This will update the `playingTrack` property of your class to the last played element.

```
this.playList.forEach( el => el.addEventListener('play', {
  this.playingTrack = el;
}));
```

Now your restart function doesn't need to loop through the array.  It just needs to play that track.

```
this.playingTrack?.play();
```

Presumably you won't call this function until after you have started playing the first track, but I am using the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator just to be safe.

Comment: Thank you very much, I managed to find a solution on my own but this one is much more elegant and needed much less code, which makes it smarter than mine.