# Find the pause song with active time on a playlist

Tags: javascript, playlist

I made a playlist for a game, the playlist play the songs randomly. When the player pause he game I stop the playlist like this:

```
...
    if(this.gameState === GAMESTATE.PAUSED) {
             
                    for(i = 0; i < this.playList.length; i++) {
                        if(this.playList[i].play()) {
                            this.playList[i].pause();
                        } 
            }
        }
...
```

But I don't know how to restart the playlist at the same current moment as it was before the paused state when the player runs the game again, and continue the random style.

Comment: is `this.playList` an array of class instances, each having methods `play()` and `pause()` that return a boolean? Please include the purpose of each variable and its type.

Comment: Look @atultw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67609766/how-to-stop-a-playlist-of-a-game-when-the-game-state-is-pause-and-play-again-whe

Comment: Each variable is a song for example this.playlist[0] = this.song1; and song1 = document.getElementById('song1'); and the HTML is <audio src="music/song1" id="song1"> @atultw